# Batch - how to multiply something by 1.5

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to multiply something by 1.5, but the number just stays the same. Multiplying the same thing by 2 works, though.

```
set /a expcap=%expcap%*1.5  Doesn't work

set /a expcap=%expcap%*2  Works
```

Comment: Batch by default will round off as it does not support fractions. You need to build some intelligence (hacks) into it.

Comment: Oh boy. That sounds pretty complicated.

Comment: not really, you need to at least know or learn `batch` though, but it would be best to use other tools such as vbscript rather.

Comment: see answer below.

Comment: if an integer result is enough then `set /a expcap=%expcap%*3/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a vbs file called `fraction.vbs` and add this:

```
WScript.Echo Eval(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

then in the same directory. `fractions.cmd`

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo fractions.vbs "3*1.5"') do (
  echo %%a
)
```

Then simply run `fractions.cmd`

This example will do `3 x 1.5 = 4,5`

you can therefore add this to your main script and simply use your `%expcap%` variable in the calculation.

Comment: Although this is a bit too much just to make the EXP cap increase by 1.5 times every level up in a simple RPG game, it works!